# Sum when value of a certain cell changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a leaky faucet at home. I put under a 20-liter bucket that will be emptied several times a day.
I create a table where:
B2 = quantity of water present in the bucket at any time (e.g. I enter 2 (liters) at 7.00)
B3 = flow rate of the leak (e.g. 3 liters / h)
B4 = calculation of the time remaining to fill the bucket (simple mathematical operations)
B5 = Time when I will have to empty the bucket (NOW () + B4)

At this point I close the sheet. After some time I don't remember what time I had to empty the bucket ... I reopen the sheet but instantly the value of B5 changes (since the value of NOW () has changed)
So ... I need the sum NOW + B4 to be calculated only if I change the content of B2, on the contrary the value of B5 must remain that of the last calculation made so that I can consult it at any time.

N.B. The value of B2 is entered several times during the day (for example I emptied the bucket before it was full and I have to redo the calculations ...)

Unfortunately I have no practice with scripts and this case also serves me to understand whether to invest my time in understanding them.

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to insert the current date in a cell is to press `Control + ;` or `⌘;`. See the [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) help page.

You can also use an `onEdit(e)` script to create static timestamps. Search this forum for many examples, or use the [timestampMultipleColumns_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/28719648?msgid=28825318) script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
actually before writing this post I searched 1000 examples on the internet but I always found very complex situations.
I would need a simple script that does:

if B2 is modified it updates the value of the sum (now + b4) in cell B5
if B2 is not modified it leaves B5 as it was before.

I can also put the NOW function in another cell (ex. A7) so B5 will become SUM (A7 + B4)

Thanks again

Comment: I would recommend that you use a keyboard shortcut to enter the current time in cell `A7` instead of using `=now()`.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for support.